# How can I split an array into n parts?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, split

I have a list of bytes and I want to split this list into smaller parts.

```
var array = new List<byte> {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
```

This list has 6 cells. For example, I want to split it into 3 parts containing each 2 bytes.

I have tried to write some for loops and used 2D arrays to achieve my purpose but I don't know it is a correct approach.

```cs
byte[,] array2D = new byte[window, lst.Count / window];
var current = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        array2D[i, j] = lst[current++];
    }
}
```

Comment: how about your code? looks like it works, although the `rows` and `cols` are still unclear here. the `rows` should be `window` and `cols` should be `lst.Count/window`.

Comment: Use morelinq batch https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs

Answer (score 82, accepted):

A nice way would be to create a generic/extension method to split any array. This is mine:

```
/// <summary>
/// Splits an array into several smaller arrays.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the array.</typeparam>
/// <param name="array">The array to split.</param>
/// <param name="size">The size of the smaller arrays.</param>
/// <returns>An array containing smaller arrays.</returns>
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this T[] array, int size)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < (float)array.Length / size; i++)
    {
        yield return array.Skip(i * size).Take(size);
    }
}
```

Moreover, this solution is deferred. Then, simply call `Split(size)` on your array.

```
var array = new byte[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
var splitArray = array.Split(2);
```

As requested, here is a generic/extension method to get a square 2D arrays from an array:

```
/// <summary>
/// Splits a given array into a two dimensional arrays of a given size.
/// The given size must be a divisor of the initial array, otherwise the returned value is <c>null</c>,
/// because not all the values will fit into the resulting array.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="array">The array to split.</param>
/// <param name="size">The size to split the array into. The size must be a divisor of the length of the array.</param>
/// <returns>
/// A two dimensional array if the size is a divisor of the length of the initial array, otherwise <c>null</c>.
/// </returns>
public static T[,]? ToSquare2D<T>(this T[] array, int size)
{
    if (array.Length % size != 0) return null;

    var firstDimensionLength = array.Length / size;
    var buffer = new T[firstDimensionLength, size];

    for (var i = 0; i < firstDimensionLength; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            buffer[i, j] = array[i * size + j];
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: This **changes** the desired data structure of the OP **totally**. He wants `square 2D arrays`.

Comment: Not really. His `square 2D arrays` is an approach he tried to solve the issue, not what he want to get. Using `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` is a lot more flexible.

Comment: Of course I would go for the something like `IEnumerable stuff` or `List stuff`. But it seems to be what the OP wants. You can't be such sure. In fact if you do some calculations with `Matrix`, using `square 2D arrays` would be better.

Comment: In fact i am trying to perform some calculations and it is better to use `matrix` or `square 2D array`. This `samples = reshape(Data,M,N);` is a method in matlab and trying to write same method in c#. It converts the data `M*N` matrices and then i should perform this equation for samples or segments `sqrt(sum(samples.*samples))`. Any suggestion? Also thank you for your replies.

Comment: Split method looks like correct. 
But ToSquare2D has errors. 
At least it should be `buffer[i, j] = array[i * size + j];` 
(i * size instead of i)
With this correction code will work if array really contains size^2 elements, in other case IndexOutOfRangeException will be thrown, so additional improvements are needed.

Comment: Hi @Anatoliy, you are right! I have fixed the code snippet in my answer, by (1) applying your suggested change, so the values are correctly picked and (2) enforcing the `size` argument to be a divisor of the length of the initial array. Thanks to that, I could remove the `Ceiling` of the length of the first dimension.

Answer (score 16):

using [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx)

```
public List<List<byte>> SplitToSublists(List<byte> source)
{
    return source
             .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
             .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 100)
             .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
             .ToList();
}
```

Simply use it

```
var sublists = SplitToSublists(lst);
```

Comment: Dont use this. I tried it and its extremely slow. What is the time complexity of this snippet? I would discourage anyone from using it.

Answer (score 7):

This to have list of lists

```
array.Select((s,i) => array.Skip(i * 2).Take(2)).Where(a => a.Any())
```

Or this to have list of items

```
array.SelectMany((s,i) => array.Skip(i * 2).Take(2)).Where(a => a.Any())
```

Comment: This is the right answer actually. Just using `Take()` and `Skip()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use IEnumerable.Chunk()
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Function splitArrayIntoSmallerArrays(Of someObject)(arrayOfSomeObject As someObject(), chunkSize As Integer) As List(Of someObject())

    Dim output = New List(Of someObject())
    Dim newestArray = New List(Of someObject)
    For i = 0 To arrayOfSomeObject.Count - 1

        newestArray.Add(arrayOfSomeObject(i))
        If newestArray.Count = chunkSize Then
            output.Add(newestArray.ToArray)
            newestArray = New List(Of someObject)
        End If
    Next
    output.Add(newestArray.ToArray)
    Return output
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to give this a try.

```
var bytes = new List<byte>(10000);
int size = 100;
var lists = new List<List<byte>>(size);
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Count; i += size)
{
        var list = new List<byte>();
        list.AddRange(bytes.GetRange(i, size));
        lists.Add(list);
}
```

Comment: This fails and goes out of bounds; you need to replace the "GetRange(i, size)" with "GetRange( i, Math.Min( size, bytes.Count - i ) )"

Answer (score -1):

If you have an array to be divided but the division has the rest with this simple solution you can share the elements missing into the various "chunks" equally:

```
    public static List<int[]> SplitArrey(int[] arrInput, int nColumn) {

    List<int[]> result = new List<int[]>(nColumn);

    int itemsForColum = arrInput.Length / nColumn;  
    int countSpareElement = arrInput.Length - (itemsForColum * nColumn);    

    // Add and extra space for the spare element
    int[] newColumLenght = new int[nColumn];
    for (int i = 0; i < nColumn; i++)
    {
        int addOne = (i < countSpareElement) ? 1 : 0;
        newColumLenght[i] = itemsForColum + addOne;
        result.Add(new int[itemsForColum + addOne]);
    }

    // Copy the values
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nColumn; i++)
    {
        int count_items_to_copy = newColumLenght[i];
        Array.Copy(arrInput, offset, result[i], 0, count_items_to_copy);
        offset += newColumLenght[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then:

```
int[] arrInput = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
var result = SplitArrey(arrInput, 5);
foreach (var item in result) {
 Console.WriteLine("   {0}", String.Join(" ", item));
}
```

the result is:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 
9 10 
11 12
```