# c# For every 7 letters in the string add item string to Listbox

Tags: c#, text, listbox

```
ListBox box = GetListBox(); //placeholder for the sample
string s = "123456776543219898989";
char[] c = s.ToCharArray();
for(int i=0;i<c.Length;i+=7)
{
    box.Items.Add(new string(c, i, 7));
}
```

This is fast way to separate text.

Comment: What part did you have an issue with?  This answer has something that might do what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18987605/507793

Comment: By "post some code," psoshmo didn't mean to overwrite your original question with the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do an easy for loop

```
ListBox box = null;//set it yourself
for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i+= 7)
{
    box.Items.Add(s.SubString(i, Math.Min(s.Length - i, 7));
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest throwing in a `Math.Min(s.Length - i, 7)` for the 3rd argument of `Substring` in case OP decides to copy/paste and apply this solution (blindly) elsewhere to a non -`% 7 == 0` `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Break the string into a character array, and use that to create your items. This string constructor overload will help:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131424.aspx

This code is just a sample. What you actually need will depend on how you want to handle the situation where the number of characters in the original string is not evenly divisible by 7.

```
ListBox box = GetListBox(); //placeholder for the sample
string s = "123456776543219898989";
char[] c = s.ToCharArray();
for(int i=0;i<c.Length;i+=7)
{
    box.Items.Add(new string(c, i, 7));
}
```

I could also do this directly on the string, instead of creating the array, but this should be much faster than calling `.SubString()` repeatedly.

Comment: -1 for saying this would be faster than SubString. String is an array of characters, array access is O(1). So both methods takes about equal amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "123456776543219898989";
int count = 0;
var parts = str.GroupBy(_ => count++ / 7)
               .Select(x => string.Concat(x))
               .ToArray();

listBox1.Items.AddRange(parts);
```